# trigonometric equation help sought

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\alpha_4, A_1, A_2, A_3$, and $B_1$ be non-zero real numbers. Consider the set of equations
$$
\begin{split}
\alpha_4\cos(3\omega\tau) &= A_1+A_2\cos(2\omega\tau)-A_3\sin(2\omega\tau)\\
\alpha_4\sin(3\omega\tau) &= B_1+A_3\cos(2\omega\tau)+A_2\sin(2\omega\tau)
\end{split}
$$
where $\tau,\omega\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$. I need to solve the above set of equations for $\omega\tau$. I've tried squaring both sides and then adding; but this hasn't helped! I've tried using trig identities; this hasn't helped either. Someone out there has to have an idea!

Comment: are you familiar with complex number? You can use the fact that $\sin(\alpha) = \frac{e^{i\alpha} - e^{-i\alpha}}{2i}$ and $\cos(\alpha) = \frac{e^{i\alpha} + e^{-i\alpha}}{2}$

Comment: many times it is easier to deal with $e^{i\alpha}$ than $\sin(\alpha)$... exponential has many nice properties that simplify the calculations...

Comment: In this case the conversion to exponential form is not helpful

Answer (score 1):

if you write 
$$\phi = \omega \tau$$ 
and 
$$\theta = tan^{-1}\frac{A_3}{A_2}$$
and
$$\lambda = \sqrt{(A_2)^2+(A_3)^2}$$
and
$$
C=A_1 + iB_1
$$
then, multiplying the second equation by $i$ gives you (something like)
$$
\alpha_4 e^{3\phi i} = \lambda e^{i(\theta+2\phi)} +C
$$
these details may not be quite right - unfortunately i am rather busy right now, and my calculations are unreliable at the best of times, but this seems the most fruitful way to proceed with the simplification

Comment: Actually, following your suggestion, I get the following equation $\alpha_4 e^{3i\phi}=C_1+C_2 e^{2i\phi}$, where $C_1:=A_1+iB_1$ and $C_2:=A_2+iA_3$. The trick is to multiply the 2nd equation by $I$, as you suggested, and then add the two equations. One then uses the exponential form of a complex number to arrive at what I got. Nonetheless, I'm still not sure how one could explicitly solve for $\phi$ in terms of the other parameters. Any ideas?

Comment: $\phi$ denotes $\omega\tau$.

Comment: Presumably, one could let $x=e^{I\phi}$, and then end up with the complex cubic $\alpha_4 x^3 -C_2x^2-C_1=0$. But how does one even begin to solve a polynomial like this one?

Comment: well solving a cubic, though not easy to do manually except in specially favorable cases, is a completely known process. for practical purposes you could try some math software. i've no personal knowledge of this, but there are people on MSE who would know all about it. the standard reduced form is the one with the squared term removed by a linear transformation of the variable, but yours is already in this form (if you simply set $z=\frac1{x}$), so it's all over bar the shouting, as we say in Yorkshire.

Comment: I want analytic solutions, not numerical ones. The process of analytically solving a cubic is known, but it is rather clumsy and cumbersome.